# Elsevier manuscript template for Engineering Science and Technology, an International Journal

Tags: word-to-latex

Can anyone tell the latex template for Engineering Science and Technology, an International Journal [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hZHp.png) its only word template

Comment: Since it's part of Elsevier, for initial sibmission, you may well use `elsarticle`, unless explicitly stated otherwise.

Comment: also before posting a new question, consider accepting the answers for your previous question (if you find them useful).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Did you contact the journal's editorial office for information on a suitable LaTeX template? If so, what did you learn?

Comment: Is this issue solved? How?